# javascript 'go to page' form script

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I need to setup a form on my site which will enable people to quickly navigate to a page by typing a number into a form and clicking 'go'.

I've got the following code which works in part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goTo()
{
window.location = document.forms[0].where.value ;
return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return goTo()">
<input type="text" name="where" value="Enter page number" onfocus="if(this.value ==     this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm injecting this code onto a page with a url, for example, like:

www.examplesite.com/navigate

The form appears just fine on the /navigate page. Now I'd like my users to be able to type a number into the form which corresponds to a url on my site. For example to get to:

www.examplesite.com/1234

the user would type '1234' into the form and press 'Go'.

What's happening instead however is the page the script is trying to open is:

www.examplesite.com/navigate/1234

Does anyone have any idea how I could modify the script to ensure it always opens a page at the root of the site rather than a subdirectory?

Thanks in advance for any help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
window.location = "/" + document.forms[0].where.value ;
```

`/` means root. Without it the path is relative to current folder.
In some cases you can use `base` tag, have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Deleted my answer because this one is better - but I think you mean "URL" not "folder".

Comment: @MatthewGilliard actually "folder" is ok here i think , you know cause "url" is the whole address thing including hash/parameters/etc

Comment: Hi Cherniv, Thank you for replying so quickly - your solution worked perfectly. A really big help and appreciate you taking the time to look at this for me.

Comment: URLs have nothing to do with folders (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_(computing)).  "Relative URLs" are relative to  a URL.